# Showing Button Active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have many buttons in my app, Now I want to make them dynamically active, meaning if the user suppose clicks the first button, that button should have a different colour than other buttons.

i.e There are different charts in my app, if the user clicks on the button to display the first chart, the button for that should have a color green while the remaining one would have #841584

How Can I achieve that?

```
 <View style={button}>
  <Button
    style
    onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(1)}
    title="Today"
    color="#841584"
  />
  <Button
    onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(7)}
    title="1W"
    color="#841584"
  />
  <Button
    onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(30)}
    title="1M"
    color="#841584"
  />
  <Button
    onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(90)}
    title="3M"
    color="#841584"
  />
  <Button
    onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(180)}
    title="6M"
    color="#841584"
  />
  <Button
    onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(365)}
    title="1Y"
    color="#841584"
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all of your buttons should have something like this

```
<Button
  style
  onPress={() => this.changeHistoryChart(1)}
  title="Today"
  color={this.state.chosenButton === 1 ? 'red': "#841584"} // Put whatever color you like instead of red
/>
```

This chosenButton state will serve to control what button is pressed, which means that all your buttons should have different condition inside color prop that has the same number as the one you are passing in changeHistoryChart function `this.state.chosenButton === 7` and so on...

Inside changeHistoryChart do

```
this.setState({chosenButton: theNumberYouPassedAsPropToChangeHistoryChart})
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to just create a function that will return a colour based on the value given and the current history chart and call that when setting the colour of your button. For example:

```
changeHistoryChart(val) {
  this.setState({currentChart: val});
}

getButtonColour(val) {
  return val === this.state.currentChart? '#0F0' : '#841584';
}
```

I'm not really sure what's the changeHistoryChart function looks like so that's just a simple estimation of it. Then when rendering button, you can do something like:

```
<Button 
   onPress={()=>this.changeHistoryChart(365)}
   title="1Y"
   color={this.getButtonColour(365)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. define a buttons array like ["1m", "3m", ..]
2. use map func to render view
3. setState({currentIndex: index}) when press button
4. color={this.state.currentIndex === index ? 'red': "#841584"}

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked ,btw it`s a little long way;
First set a flag for each of them like:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state={
    button_1 : false,
    button_2 : false,
    button_3 : false,
    button_4 : false,
  }
```

then,for each `Button` do this:

```
 <Button
      title="Button 1"
      color={this.state.button_1 ? "green" : "gray"}
      onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                       button_1: !this.state.button_1,
                       button_2: false,
                       button_3: false,
                       button_4: false
                         });
               }}
  />

 <Button
      title="Button 2"
      color={this.state.button_2 ? "green" : "gray"}
      onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                       button_1: false,
                       button_2: !this.state.button_2,
                       button_3: false,
                       button_4: false
                         });
               }}
  />
```

do this for other Buttons too,it will work

Comment: Yes, I initially thought of the same idea but for some reason I am not a fan of making extra states in component.
I am thinking about implementing Lazar Answer but still thanks :)

Comment: @KuchBhi I searched a lot about this issue,but I didn`t find any other way to solve it,I knew just this way .